# Storing data in array dynamically

Tags: java, arrays

I looked other similar threads but i did not found the answer.

I'm doing an exercise in java. It's some kinda a fun game, which becomes "smarter" every turn. Computer tries to guess which animal i have in mind. The game looks something like that:

[image]

The problem is, i want to use two dimensional array to store **Questions**, and **Answers**. But since the program can have unlimited questions and answers, i' cant use Array object to store data because arrays aren't dynamically resizable.

So then we have ArrayList class which is good for storing objects at runtime. But i don't think that i should use two dimensional arraylist here. How would you handle this kind of situation?

Exercise also gives me hint, that if i want i may look on the internet about "binary tree". I did, but i only found some strange things that i don't understand.

Comment: I don't think 'Binary Trees' are your solution, or, main problem

Answer (score 2):

You could stick to your idea of using multi-dimensional arrays, however...try using a binary tree as hinted. Looking at the following [binary tree](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteBinaryTree.html) your answers would be 16-25 (the leaf nodes) and everything else would be a question.

So starting at the top (root) this node could be the question "does the animal have four legs?". If the answer"yes" then traverse (move) to node 2, otherwise traverse to node 3. This means that all leaf nodes under node 2 are animals with four legs and all leaf nodes under node 3 are animals that don't have four legs.

You then need to repeat the process treating node 2 or 3 as your root node until you get to a leaf node.

Answer (score 1):

All questions and animals can be stored in one binary tree. Use the **questions** as **inner nodes** and and **animals** as **leaves**. Each answer has two descendants (branching of tree is 2 = *binary tree*) either another answer, if the animal is not known yet, or a animal (leave node).

How to represent a tree in Java is another question. You may use following classes to do it (add *getters/setters/constructors/convenient methods*):

```
public class Node {
   // add here other common attributes
   private Node parent;
}

public class Question extends Node {
   private String text;
   private Node yes;
   private Node no;
}

public class Animal extends Node {
   private String name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good case for using `HashTable<QUESTION,ANIMAL>` 
you can dynamically add to it and also store the connection between the question and the animal

```
Hashtable<String,string> ht = new HashTable<String,String>();
String animal;
//adding
ht["some question"] = "some animal";

//getting
if (ht["some question"] != null)
   animal = ht["some question"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any implementation of [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to store your animal's name as key and `List` of answers as value. But the problem is that this results won't exist after exiting application. So think about [database](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136101.html) to store your values.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is bit confusing to me so this may not answer your question directly. Since you have asked about binary trees I am compiling this answer. I doubt the applicability of Binary Tree in this scenario.

Well if you are starting with Binary Tree, first learn the concept and the behavior of the Binary tree. It is simple. Anything with at most 2 branches :)

[image]

[Image Reference](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Trees/trees.html)

Forget Java and programming for a moment. These applets show you binary search tree a bit advanced version of a binary tree.

[Binary Tree Demol](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~goodrich/dsa/trees/btree.html)

[Binary Tree Demo](http://people.ksp.sk/~kuko/bak/)

Then think of programming. If you cannot read then you cannot learn. You should try to read again and again to understand stuff :)

Now here is an actual implementation you can read.

[Binary Tree - Java](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/110/BinaryTrees.html)